# Download Image file from one URL to another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, download

I have to download images from live URL and save to live Server.

Comment: Do you need download or upload? What party do you control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WebClient and download and store image, very simple :

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient;
wc.DownloadFile("http://www.site.com/image.jpg", 
                 Server.MapPath("~\images\image.jpg"));
```

of course you got to set Images directory writeable from your web app